# EXTJS: Change the color of a node

Tags: extjs

I need to be able to change the color of a node in a treepanel.  I thought this would be pretty simple, but i am having a heck of a time finding anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

of course, 5 minutes after I ask, I find the solution....

It does work without removing the current class, but I left the line there just because I don't know if it might cause problems later if its not there.

```
<style>
.RedText a span
{
color: Red;
}
</style>

var currentClass = opNode.attributes.cls;
opNode.ui.removeClass(currentClass);
opNode.ui.addClass('RedText');
opNode.attributes.cls = 'RedText';
```

Answer (score 1):

this didn't work for me. I wanted to change the style of a double clicked treeNode. Here is my solution with extjs 4.2:

…

**CSS**

```
.treeNode-selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**js e.g. itemdblclick event binding**

```
onFilterTreeItemDblClick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    var me = this;
    this.store.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function(node) {
      // if your root node is not visible
      if (node.getId() === "root") { return; }
      var nodeView = me.getView().getNodeById(node.getId());
      var td = nodeView.childNodes[0];
      if (node.getId() === record.getId()) {
         td.classList.add("treeNode-selected");
      } else {
          td.classList.remove("treeNode-selected");
      }
    }
}
```

I hope this safes somebody some time.